# How can we store into an NSDictionary? What is the difference between NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am developing an application in which I want to use an `NSDictionary`. Can anyone please send me a sample code explaining the procedure how to use an `NSDictionary` to store Data with a perfect example?

Comment: You could start by having a look at the NSDictionary documentation ...

Comment: The polite RTFMs somehow seem more caustic than the explicit ones.

Comment: @stefanB For a lot of new programmers official documentation is often very complicated and confusing so a basic view of _x_ on SO helps out.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableDictionary) docs are probably your best bet. They even have some great examples on how to do various things, like...

**...create an NSDictionary**

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1", @"key2", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects 
                                                       forKeys:keys];
```

**...iterate over it**

```
for (id key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

**...make it mutable**

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [dictionary mutableCopy];
```

*Note: historic version before 2010: [[dictionary mutableCopy] autorelease]*

**...and alter it**

```
[mutableDict setObject:@"value3" forKey:@"key3"];
```

**...then store it to a file**

```
[mutableDict writeToFile:@"path/to/file" atomically:YES];
```

**...and read it back again**

```
NSMutableDictionary *anotherDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/file"];
```

**...read a value**

```
NSString *x = [anotherDict objectForKey:@"key1"];
```

**...check if a key exists**

```
if ( [anotherDict objectForKey:@"key999"] == nil ) NSLog(@"that key is not there");
```

**...use scary futuristic syntax**

*From 2014 you can actually just type dict[@"key"] rather than [dict objectForKey:@"key"]*

Answer (score 32):

```
NSDictionary   *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"String" forKey: @"Test"];
NSMutableDictionary *anotherDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[anotherDict setObject: dict forKey: "sub-dictionary-key"];
[anotherDict setObject: @"Another String" forKey: @"another test"];

NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@, Mutable Dictionary: %@", dict, anotherDict);

// now we can save these to a file
NSString   *savePath = [@"~/Documents/Saved.data" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
[anotherDict writeToFile: savePath atomically: YES];

//and restore them
NSMutableDictionary  *restored = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: savePath];
```

Comment: @Ben Gottlieb 
Part One: 
Thanks for nice explanations. Actually i want to save two of my UItextField data in a file from MutableDictionary. Here you wrote `NSString   *savePath = [@"~/Documents/Saved.data" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];`, now my question is, what is the `Saved.data` file here? How can i made it?

Comment: @Ben Gottlieb Part Two:
And in my case i put a text file (.rtf) in the following directory `Supporting files > MediaFiles > Documents > userData.rtf`.Now can i save these type of Mutabledictionary data in text file? And what will be the perfect directory in this case? I was trying with this `[userData writeToFile:@"MediaFiles/Documents/userData.rtf" atomically:YES];` & with this `[userData writeToFile:@"Documents/userData.rtf" atomically:YES];`, but didn't work.
Have a good day.

Answer (score 18):

The key difference: **NSMutableDictionary can be modified in place, NSDictionary cannot**. This is true for all the other NSMutable* classes in Cocoa. NSMutableDictionary is a *subclass* of NSDictionary, so everything you can do with NSDictionary you can do with both. However, NSMutableDictionary also adds complementary methods to modify things in place, such as the method `setObject:forKey:`.

You can convert between the two like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutable = [[dict mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSDictionary *dict = [[mutable copy] autorelease];
```

Presumably you want to store data by writing it to a file. NSDictionary has a method to do this (which also works with NSMutableDictionary):

```
BOOL success = [dict writeToFile:@"/file/path" atomically:YES];
```

To read a dictionary from a file, there's a corresponding method:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/file/path"];
```

If you want to read the file as an NSMutableDictionary, simply use:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/file/path"];
```