# How to use plist files in cocos2d and iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game, breakout clone basically.
I got tired of making levels programmatically so I got this editor = Scenedesigner that lets you put sprites, nodes, etc on screen.

Question - how do I load that .plist file in my game and make my game understand it?

For example, I use composite objects for my sprites - for example ball is of Ball class that contains ccsprite as property, how will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about how you created your plist, but this post about using **NSDictionary** should should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760384/388412

...it's basically the same for **NSArray**, both classes can store objects and read from and write to file/URL (thus reading and writing plists).

So, you probably should have rather started with a dictionary or array and write that to file to create a plist. As the other way round might cause problems depending on the format of your specific plist.

As for more complex serialization, you should look into the **NSCoding** protocol. With that you can serialize and deserialize whole object trees (using **NSArchiver** and **NSUnarchiver**). Though, don't use NSArchiver/NSUnarchiver separately, better make your classes NSCoding compliant.

If your case is less complex, I recommend starting with NSDictionary / NSArray serialization as it's a bit easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` method of `NSDictionary` and 
`arrayWithContentsOfFile` method of `NSArray` to convert your plist into the array or dictionary depending upon the content of plist.