# how to store in sqlite database from json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sqlite

I create one application and I read many data in table View from JSON and I want parsed this JSON and store in sqlite  but I dont know from where should I start?

this is parsed my json code :

```
@implementation TableViewController
{
    NSArray *news;
    NSMutableData *data;
    NSString *title;
    NSMutableArray *all;
}
@synthesize mainTable;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"News";
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zacandcatie.com/YouTube/json.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [con start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    for (int i =0; i < [news count]; i++)
    {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
    title =[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+i]objectForKey:@"title"];
        if (!all) {
            all = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
        [all addObject:title];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",all);

    [mainTable reloadData];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The Connection has been LOST" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

you my json url. I want store "title"&"date_string" value in sqlite.
please guide me!!!

Comment: You can use dictionary instead of sqlite db

Comment: ok I know But I dont know what I do?

Comment: I dont know how to store Dictionary in table on sqlite!!!

Comment: Here is an answered question of "[How can we store data into an NSDictionary?][1]"


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760371/how-can-we-store-into-an-nsdictionary-what-is-the-difference-between-nsdictiona

Comment: my friend my problem is that I dont know about sqlite data base and store data in it (not store dictionary) please guide me how to store nsdictionary in sqlite

Comment: Please do some independent research.  As it is you don't understand things well enough to ask meaningful questions.

Comment: Hint:  You don't store JSON data in a SQL db, nor do you store NSDictonaries in a SQL db, you store data.

Answer (score 1):

After parsing you data in the form of NSDictionary you can create a query of insert into and fire the query n your data will be save into your database

Comment: @fred create a method by which you just pass a dictionary to the method that will create a insert query along with the key and the value from the dictionary by using NSMutableString create a query.

Comment: my friend Im sorry can you tell me with code??? I do first part but in second part its my problem

Comment: i Have posted the code try this hope you will get the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)InsertRecords:(NSMutableDictionary *)dict
{

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3 *cruddb;

NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into tblName ("];

for (int i = 0; i<[[dict allKeys] count]; i++)
{
    [str appendFormat:@"%@,",[[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]];
}
[str appendFormat:@")values ("];
for (int i = 0; i<[[dict allKeys] count]; i++)
{
    [str appendFormat:@"%@,",[dict valueForKey:[[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

[str appendFormat:@");"];
NSLog(@"qry : %@",str);
const char *sql = [str UTF8String]; ;

if((sqlite3_open([database UTF8String], &cruddb)==SQLITE_OK))
{
    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) ==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_step(stmt);
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //  tableview cell setup

    NSArray* keys = [self.data allKeys];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.data objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Please refer [this](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html) links to have data in order in dictionary

[NSDictionary with ordered keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376090/nsdictionary-with-ordered-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing @Divz Ans...

you will have create the .sqlite file. And there is nothing easier than this.

There are two ways(that i know) to create sqlite file,

1> you can download **SQLite Manager** add-on in firefox, where you can manipulate data in database graphically.

Or,

2> you can use **Terminal** with a single line command, **sqlite3 dbFileName.sqlite**. enter,

where you will get **sqlite>** now start with further SQL(create/insert/update..) queries.

you can find your sqlite file at MacHD>users>admin(not shared one)>yourFile.sqlite or, finder---go>home>yourFile.sqlite

Answer (score 0):

```
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        db=[[SKDatabase alloc]initWithFile:@"student.sqlite"];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"..........Your Url............"];
        NSURLRequest *json_request=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
        NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:json_request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSMutableDictionary *dic=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSMutableArray *student_ary=[dic objectForKey:@"students"];

        for (NSMutableArray *student_info in student_ary) {
            NSMutableDictionary *insert=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
            NSMutableDictionary *info=[student_info mutableCopy];
            [insert setObject:[info objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
            [insert setObject:[info objectForKey:@"city"] forKey:@"city"];
            [db insertDictionary:insert forTable:@"student_info"];

        }
    })
```

//.m file view....

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *qry=@"select * from student_info";
    ary=[[db lookupAllForSQL:qry] mutableCopy];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```