# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while filling in the dictionary (?)

Tags: objective-c, plugins, nsdictionary

```
void CountlyRecordEventSegmentationCountSum(const char * key, const char * segmentation, int count, double sum)
{
    NSString * seg = CreateNSString(segmentation);
    NSArray * entries = [seg componentsSeparatedByString:@"`"];
    NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    for (id entry in entries)
    {
        NSArray * keyValue = [entry componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
        [dict setValue:[keyValue objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[keyValue objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    [[Countly sharedInstance] recordEvent:CreateNSString(key) segmentation:dict count:count sum:sum];
}
```

I put "?" in the title because I'm not entirely sure if the problem is in the code above but that's my best guess. I'm integrating Countly iOS plugin with Unity and one of Countly plugin's methods take `NSDictionary *` as argument. As I don't know how to send a dictionary from C# to Objective-C I'm storing my dict in a `string`, sending it to Objective-C and then recreating the dictionary (the code above).

But that's probably even not relevant. I know `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` usually has something to do with unfreed resources or sth so maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong (I don't know Objective-C at all, just writing a few lines needed by the plugin).

Edit:
From Unity sample:

```
// Converts C style string to NSString
NSString * CreateNSString (const char * string)
{
    if (string)
        return [NSString stringWithUTF8String: string];
    else
        return [NSString stringWithUTF8String: ""];
}
```

Comment: Did you try with an NSMutableDictionnary instead of the traditional NSDictionnary?

Comment: @Kirualex it is not "traditional", it is immutable. One cannot modify contents of the NSDictionary after it's initialization. One should use NSMutableDictionary instead

Comment: Check whether keyValue Array always contains 2 objects. B'coz you are using objectAtIndex:1 and objectAtIndex:0. So, not sure does it contains 2 objects. Check with a condition.

Comment: @art-divin Can I use `NSMutableDictionary *` as an argument for a function that takes `NSDictionary *` as an argument?

Comment: You can use NSMutableDictionary where ever you would use an NSDictionary normally. It is a subclass of NSDictionary. But it is mutable. Meaning, your code woud crash on sending "setValue:" to the dictionary object anyway. But that is not (yet) your problem because that would throw a different exception.

Comment: For your abort - did you set an All-Exceptions breakpoint? Doing so you will have a chance to fingerpoint on the line that causes the exception. If not, then it may get nasty.

Comment: Apparently that **was** the problem because after changing to `NSMutableDictionary *` the application doesn't crash or throw any exceptions anymore. art-divin, make your comment an answer and get accepted. ;)

Comment: Anyway, the call stack could give a hint on where the exception was thrown. Did you look at it? Click on every method of your own within the call stack and see what object is dealt with then the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you've made is that you are trying to modify immutable version of `NSDictionary`.

One cannot modify contents of the `NSDictionary` after it's initialization. You should use `NSMutableDictionary` instead.

Here is a documentation on [NSMutableDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
And here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760384/611055) of how to create mutable version of an immutable object that conforms to [NSMutableCopying](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using `NSMutableDictionary`, you can't modify an `NSDictionary`.

Also, you should use `setObject:forKey:` because `setValue:forKey:` is a KVC method.  It happens to do the same thing on an `NSMutableDictionary` for most keys, but it is marginally slower.

Finally, you should check that `[keyValue count] >= 2` before trying to access the objects at indexes 0 and 1.

**Edit** Also, `CreateNSString()` looks suspicious.  It might be either leaking or prematurely releasing the string.  But you need to post the code.  In any case, I'd use

```
 seg = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: segment];
```

or, other appropriate method if segment is not encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: `CreateNSString()` is from Unity sample, posted the code in edit to my question.