# How to add sqlite database values into an array?I was retrived but how can I put these values into array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sqlite

1) How to add sqlite database values into an array.
2) I was retrived my sqlite database values but how can I put these values into an array for to show the another viewcontroller tableview.
3) What can I write in viewcontroller.h and viewcontroller.m .
4) Below one I wrote but it getting error "No known class method for selector'getData'"

Code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

    [super viewDidLoad];

   depositArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    depositData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    depositArray=[dbModelClass getData:str];

    for( NSDictionary *dis in depositArray)
    {
        [depositData addObject:[dis objectForKey:@"depositTable"]];
    }
```

Comment: Well, what type is dbModelClass declared to be?  Presumably not a class that defines a `getData:` method.  (Or, if it's really saying "No known CLASS method" then I suspect that "dbModelClass" is a class name, and `getData:` is an instance method (ie, `-` vs `+`).)

Comment: Looking at your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937468/how-to-add-sqlite-database-values-into-an-array-and-how-to-add-these-values-into), I see that "dbModelClass" is a class name, and it has a class method named `getData`.  Note that `getData` is NOT the same as `getData:`.

Comment: (And please learn standard C/C++/Objective-C/Java naming conventions:  Class names should begin with a capital letter, and the names of fields and methods and local variables should begin with a lower-case letter.)

Comment: (You need to purchase a good tutorial on iPhone programming and study it.  You can't learn the language simply by blindly copying examples you find on the net.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you `#import` the header that declares the incorrectly named `getData:` method?

Note:  If you are writing raw SQL, you are wasting your time.  Use FMDB (or similar) if you need database portability beyond iOS/OS X.   If you are targeting only iOS / OS X, then Core Data is an excellent solution that has a very tight integration with the system.

---

Some other issues:

This makes no sense:

```
 depositArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 depositArray=[dbModelClass getData:str];
```

The first line allocates an array.  The second line immediately assigns a new value to the variable pointing to that original array, both losing the reference to it and leaking memory.

Also, methods should not be prefixed with `get`.   That is reserved for very specific use cases.