# Why does [copy] affected the NSArray in Xcode

Tags: nsarray, nsdictionary

The following was coded in a while loop

`[array_stations addObject:[dic_stations copy]];`

`[array_stations addObject:dic_stations ];`

What is the differences between them? if `[copy]` is not included, all the dictionary item will be the same inside the while loop, while `NSLog` the array.

If `[copy]` is added, all the items are list normally.

Thanks.

Comment: Uh, in the first case you get a copy.  In the second case the original.

Comment: There are says 10 items in `array_station`, (I use a WHILE LOOP to add item to an array) if I don't use `[copy]`, all the records in that array are the same.

Comment: Like I said, in the first case you get a copy, in the second case the original.  If you add the original to an array, modify it, and add it again, you will get the SAME object twice, so obviously "they" will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

`[dic_stations copy]` represents object of `nsmutabledictionary`. `dic_stations` represents object of `nsdictionary`. For more details [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760371/how-can-we-store-into-an-nsdictionary-what-is-the-difference-between-nsdictiona).

Comment: Actually, we have no idea what type dic_stations is.  It could be a Kumquat.