# NSDictionary's key names changes after an NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a weird problem.

> M_DrugListRow have these properties:NAME,SEGMENT,ATTRIBUTE,COLORCODE,ID,DESCRIPTION
>
> dict have these drug_name,segment,attribute,colorcode,..

```
M_DrugListRow *m= [[M_DrugListRow alloc]initDrugRow:[arr_for_picker objectAtIndex:row] val:0]
[dict setValue:m.NAME forKeyPath:@"drug_name"];
```

After this code dict has M_DrugListRow's keys(NAME,SEGMENT,ATTRIBUTE,COLORCODE,DESCRIPTION), not his own keys(name,segment,attribute,colorcode,drug_name)
So it gives error in my code.

If I change it into this code, it works:

```
[dict setValue:[[arr_for_picker objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@NAME"] forKeyPath:@"drug_name"];
```

I use the first type too much. But it isn't efficiant. Why is that happening and how can I solve this?

Code:
M_DrugListRow.h

```
             @interface M_DrugListRow : M_Drug
-(id)initDrugRow:(M_Drug*)drugModel val:(NSInteger)val
{
    self=[super init];
    
    @try {
        
        self=[self initDrug:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject:drugModel]];
        liquid =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        method =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        
        if(val){
            liquid= [DataAccessLiquid drugliquid:[VC_Login getGuid] drug_id:self.ID];
            method= [DataAccessMethod:[VC_Login getGuid] drug_id:self.ID];
            
        }
        
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        
    }
    @finally {
        
    }
    return self;
}
```

M_Drug.h

```
   -(id)initDrug:(NSDictionary*)par
    {
        self=[super init];
        dict =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:par];
        @try {
            ATTRIBUTE1= [par valueForKey:@"ATTRIBUTE1"];
            NAME= [par valueForKey:@"NAME"];
            COLORCODE= [[par valueForKey:@"COLORCODE"]boolValue];
            DESCRIPTION= [par valueForKey:@"DESCRIPTION"];
            SEGMENT= [par valueForKey:@“SEGMENT”];
            ID= [[par valueForKey:@"ID"]integerValue];
            
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            
        }
        @finally {
            
        }
        
        return self;
    }
```

Comment: please post the `initDrugRow:value:` method

Comment: What error are you seeing? Can we see M_DrugListRow.h ? It's hard to see what is happening here without more information

Comment: @akashg I post the code. [<__NSDictionaryI 0x9d830a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key drug_name

Comment: try using [dict setObject: forKey:]

Comment: Didn't work. But the problem is something effects to dict and change the keys. :/ I couldn't find why. But the keys are all the properties of only M_Drug.

Comment: Maybe because yu are using a NSDictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary

Comment: I'm modifyng code and then I will try it.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary worked. Thank you :) Can you write it as answer , so I can mark it

Comment: @akashg can you write it as answer so i can mark it?

Comment: @user3309441 have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`. This is a subclass of NSDictionary and is editable.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760384/2043580) for a good explanation.

An example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mdict = [[NSMutableDicionary alloc]init];
[mdict setObject:@"Hello World!" forKey:@"whateverKey"]
```

Read up on the class reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).