# Android basicnamevaluepair list in iOS

Tags: android, ios, json, basicnamevaluepair

I am new in iOS, in android i call web service using basicnamevaluepair list in android but in iOS how it code?
in android it's work fine but in iOS I send data in JSON dictionary format also try in string format but it's not working , what is equivalent of basicnamevaluepair in iOS

thanks

Comment: or check out the link for more info ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey

Comment: objectforkey is same as basicnamevaluepair?

Comment: @Theorist Plz Accept the answer if it answered your question well.

Comment: @bhavin if u post any code example in Both android and ios then good for better understanding.

Comment: @theroist you want to store an array or just string value...

Comment: @Theorist you post an android code...i post a code relevant to it

Comment: give me simple example in both , i don't have code in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you use `NameValuePairs` in Android, in iOS `NSDictionary` is used. Using this you can store multiple values / objects (even arrays and stuff) using a `key` (which is equivalent to the `Name` part in `NameValuePair`)

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760371/how-can-we-store-into-an-nsdictionary-what-is-the-difference-between-nsdictiona) of how to use this.

Just for a quick overlook here is how it works in android

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value"));
```

And here is how it works in iOS

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{"key" : @"Hello there!"};
```

Comment: if u post any code example in Both android and ios  then good for better understanding.